# Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Let $f:A \rightarrowtail B$ and $g:B \rightarrowtail A$ be injections. Then there exists a bijection from $A$ to $B$.

$\textit{Proof}$: WLOG assume $A\cap B=\emptyset$. We now make a partition of $A \cup B$ into "chains". First, we take an arbitrary $a_0 \in A$, map it with $f$, then map $f(a_0)$ with $g$, then map $g(f(a_0))$ with $f$ etc. Hence we obtain $4$ possibilities.

$1)$ The chain is a cycle: $a_0 \mapsto b_0 \mapsto a_1 \mapsto \cdots \mapsto a_k \mapsto b_k \mapsto a_0.$

$2)$ The chain goes to infinity on at least one end. If we can, we expand the chain to the left. Meaning, if $a_0$ is in $Im(g)$, we put $g^{-1}(a_0)$ to the left, then check if that is in $Im(f)$ and so on. This yields 3 cases:

$2.1)$ It stretches on both sides infinitely.

$$
\cdots \mapsto a_0\mapsto b_0 \mapsto a_1 \mapsto b_1 \mapsto \cdots
$$

$2.2)$ It ends to the left with some element from $A$ which isn't in $Im(g)$:

$$
a_0\mapsto b_0 \mapsto a_1 \mapsto b_1 \mapsto \cdots
$$

$2.3)$ It ends to the left with some element from $B$ which isn't in $Im(f)$:

$$
b_0\mapsto a_0 \mapsto b_1 \mapsto a_1 \mapsto \cdots
$$

In the three cases above, we just change the numeration when we have achieved our goal. The bijection which we want to get is then simply defined as $F:A \to B$, $F(a_i):=b_i$.

My question is this: At the beginning of the proof we assume WLOG that $A \cap B = \emptyset$. Is this WLOG because in case they aren't disjoint, we can make them such? For example, work with $A' = A\times \{ 1\}$ and $B' = B\times \{2\}$, which are clearly disjoint?

And on another note, I just want to check if I understand this correctly. When we are done with $a_0$, we then pick some $a\in A$ which isn't already a part of the chain which we previously constructed, right? This need not end after constructing a chain for $a_0$?

EDIT: For example (a fairly trivial one), if we have $A=\{ 1,2,3 \}$ and $B = \{ 4,5,6 \}$, and make two injective mappings:
$$
1\mapsto 4, 2\mapsto 5, 3\mapsto 6,
$$
and
$$
4\mapsto 1, 5\mapsto 3, 6\mapsto 2,
$$
then the chains would be
$$
1\mapsto 4 \mapsto 1, \ 2\mapsto 5 \mapsto 3 \mapsto 6 \mapsto 2.
$$
So if we were to take $1\in A$, we wouldn't generate a partition of $A\cup B$ if we didn't continue and pick another element in $A$.

Comment: Any element  $a \in A$ which is in a cycle, as in your list in 1), can map to the $b$ immediately following it. [So the collection of $a$'s in cycles is another cell in the partition of $A$, which thus may contain up to four cells.] For each element of $A$ one must decide which cell it is in, and then map into $B$ according to how that cell should map. The first cell which you call 1), and the two cells denoted 2.1) and 2.2), map "forward" to the next $b$ while those in dell denoted 2.3) map "backward" to the previous $b.$

Answer (score 1):

It seems the idea here is that the three "cases" you have make a pairwise disjoint union of three sets with union $A$. Then the map can be defined by looking at each $a$ in $A$ and if it is in one of the first two cases, map it to the $b$ value immediately *after* it, while in the third case map it to the $b$ value immediately *before* it. [You have to 'go backward" in case 3 in order to make sure the map is a bijection (onto $B$). It's clearly an injection...] This is likely what you meant by "change the numeration" but I wasn't sure.

Note: the partition of $A$ should also contain a cell for what is called 1) of the post, elements in cycles.

Your first question about WLOG $A \cap B$ being empty is treatable exactly as you suggest with Cartesian products, if they are not initially disjoint.

[Note I may delete this, it seems now to me the OP already had it figured out.]

Comment: I just made an edit describing with an example what I meant with the second question. You're right about case $2.3$ though. And yes, that's why we change the numeration. :)